# Register MBean Every time before using it

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I am registering MBean in a common class while booting up tomcat application. Trying to access this bean in some other class to record some statistics. But JMX Bean values are not getting updated in the JConsole.

To instantiate the MBean I tried

1. `MBeanImplClass = new MBeanImplClass();`
2. `MBeanInterface= new MBeanInterface();`

Do I have to register MBean, everytime I use it?

Answer (score 0):

No, but, you need to make sure the bean that is registered, and the bean that is being updated with new statistics are the same instance. One way to do this is to implement your bean as a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java).

Comment: Is there any way to access bean from MBeanServer?

Comment: Sure. I will suggest an approach in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215527/jmxbean-entries-are-not-showing-up